# Error when saving record due to Lookup field filter

Tags: lookup-filter

[image]

Getting the following standard error message with a lookup filter validation rule. I have checked all of the lookup fields on the object (Opportunity) and cannot see any lookup filters that would block it.

Is there another way to debug this and see what is blocking it?

Comment: try using the `Execution Overview` panel on the developer console. then on the `Save Order` tab, you have access to a list of all processes executed in the transaction, and from there you can identify which one is preventing the record from being saved.

Comment: (You might have to change the Debug Levels to a finer level to see the info you need)

Comment: Perfect. got it. Thank you both